# Split in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, split

```
 {
    _id: ObjectId("624ab34913b144c54b3c9ad4"),
    PlayerName: 'Novak Djokovic',
    Born: 'Belgrade, Serbia',
    Height: 188,
    Hand: 'Right-Handed, Two-Handed Backhand',
    LinkPlayer: 'https://www.atptour.com/en/players/novak-djokovic/d643/player-activity?year=all&matchType=Singles',
    Tournament: 'Tokyo Olympics',
    Location: 'Tokyo, Japan',
    Date: '2021.07.26 - 2021.08.01',
    Ground: 'Hard',
    Prize: '',
    GameRound: 'Quarter-Finals',
    GameRank: 69,
    Oponent: 'Kei Nishikori',
    WL: 'W',
    Score: '62 60'
  }
```

This is an example of a collection I have to work on.
How can I separate the location, and have one field called city for the first value and another one for country with the second value?

I know I have to use aggregate - db.atpplayers.aggregate() in this case - and with the function $split.
I got to this one db.atpplayers.aggregate([{$project:{city:{$split:["$Location",","]}}}]), but I got this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("624ab34913b144c54b3c9ad4"),
    city: [ 'Tokyo', ' Japan' ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the same aggregation you have you only need to add another stage to use the first value of the array as City and the second as Country.

You can use `$first` and `$last` to achieve that:

```
{
  "$project": {
    "city": {
      "$first": "$city"
    },
    "country": {
      "$last": "$city"
    }
  }
}
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jUg9SgBcmgg)